# Use phone keyboard to control PES on Android phone?

Tags: android, pro-evolution-soccer-2012

I installed Pro Evolution Soccer on my Android phone but I can't find any setting to change the game control method to keyboard instead of the touch screen.

Is it possible to phone keyboard to control PES on Android phone?

Comment: If you try using something like a Bluetooth keyboard despite the settings does it still work?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way of changing settings because most of the Android Phones are only touch screen and doesn't have physical keypad. Thats the reason for no keyboard settings in PES because the game package is built for common features, keeping in mind that most of the phone supports that and as i already explained only some android phones have physical keypad.